# How to Input Questions in My C++ Quiz?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++

I'm working on a quiz project in C++ at the moment, and I'm confused as to how to make some of it work. I have a class (quiz) which sets up the rules for how the quiz works. It looks like this:

```
class quiz
{
private:
    //how many questions
    int num_q;
    char answer[50];
    string question[50];

    int pom;
    string plus;
    string minus;

public:
    quiz()
    {
        pom = 0;
    }
    void set_pom_answers(string pluss, string minuss)
    {
        plus = pluss;
        minus = minuss;
    }
    void set_num_q(int num_qq)
    {
        num_q = num_qq;
    }
    //Question_Number = question number, ca = correct answer, and q = question
    void set_q_a(int Question_Number, string q, char ca)
    {
        question[Question_Number - 1] = q;
        answer[Question_Number - 1] = ca;
    }
    void run_quiz()
    {
        char ans;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_q; i++)
        {
            cout << question[i] << ": ";
            cin >> ans;
            if (ans == answer[i])
            {
                cout << "Correct! good for you!" << endl;
                pom = pom + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Wrong. :(" << endl;
                pom = pom;

            }
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }
        if (pom >= (num_q / 2))
        {
            cout << plus << endl;
            cout << "your score was " << pom << endl;
        }
        else if (pom < (num_q / 2))
        {
            cout << minus << endl;
            cout << "your score was " << pom << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "input not recognised" << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
    }

};
```

To run a quiz using this, you use a format like this in Main():

```
        quiz Politics;
        Politics.set_num_q(10);
        Politics.set_pom_answers("You're good at Politics.", "Revise more!");
        Politics.set_q_a(1, "Michael Fallon is the current foreign secretary: [t]rue or [f]alse", 'f');
        Politics.set_q_a(2, "Tony Blair was PM from 1996-2007: [t]rue or [f]alse", 'f');
        Politics.set_q_a(3, "Michael Gove is the current education secretary : [t]rue or [f]alse", 'f');
        Politics.set_q_a(4, "Teresa May is the current home secretary: [t]rue or [f]alse", 't');
        Politics.set_q_a(5, "Owen Jones is a blairite: [t]rue or [f]alse", 'f');
        Politics.set_q_a(6, "Nick Robinson is the BBC's political editor: [t]rue or [f]alse", 'f');
        Politics.set_q_a(7, "David Cameron is a eurosceptic: [t]rue or [f]alse", 't');
        Politics.set_q_a(8, "Matthew Handcock is a Tory MP: [t]rue or [f]alse", 't');
        Politics.set_q_a(9, "Jonathon Woodcock is a Labour MP: [t]rue or [f]alse", 't');
        Politics.set_q_a(10, "David McDonell is the current shadow chancellor: [t]rue or [f]alse", 'f');
```

The above works absolutely fine when I run it using Politics.run_quiz().

The issue is that I want to create a menu that allows me to make or take the quizzes, and I am confused as to how I code the maker part. In the end I want to save this information to a file, and when the user selects 'take' in the menu, they will load this file and the quiz will be run from it. So far, I have this just as an example to illustrate what I want:

```
int main()
    {

        int Choice;

        do {
            cout << "Would you like to:\n\n" << "1)Make a quiz?\n" << "2) Take a quiz?\n" << "3) Quit?\n\n";
            cin >> Choice;
        } while (Choice > 3);       

        if (Choice == 1) {
            string Quiz_Name;
            cout << "What is the name of this quiz?\n";
            cin >> Quiz_Name;

            int Num_of_Qs;
            cout << "How many Questions should there be?\n";
            cin >> Num_of_Qs;

            string Answer_Plus;
            cout << "What message should be displayed if the score is above 50%?\n";
            cin >> Answer_Plus;

            string Answer_Minus;
            cout << "What message should be displayed if the score is less that 50%?\n";
            cin >> Answer_Minus;

            /*Here I would like to add all the elements together, along with the questions and answers. for example:

            quiz Quiz_Name;
            Quiz_Name.set_num_q(Num_of_Qs);
            Quiz_Name.set_pom_answers(Answer_Plus, Answer_Minus);

            for (int j = 1; j <= Num_of_Qs; j++) {
            Quiz_Name.set_q_a(j, [The user inputs a question], [the user inputs an answer])
            }

            or something along those lines? How would I make something like this work?

            */


        }

        if (Choice == 2) {
            Politics.run_quiz();
        }

        if (Choice == 3) {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

I have no idea whether this is the best way to go about it or not? Could someone please help me work out how to make a quiz using user inputs?

Thanks!

Comment: You just asked this same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433594/how-to-save-questions-in-my-c-quiz).  you should not delete and then re-ask the same question.

Comment: I apologise, I've never really used SO before and assumed deleting it would actually get rid of it.|

However, as you see I've added detail so as to not be vague—a problem with my previous question.

Comment: And that is why you fix your previous question.  As is your question is still to broad.

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfectly fine way to do it. It is as far as I know the 'best' way to do it (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Keep in mind though that you shouldn't use `cin >> str`, as it stops at   (whitespace). `getline(cin, str)` stops at `\n`, which is what you want as the input can contain white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR.

I recommend using a structure that has the question and answer:

```
class Question_Answer
{
  std::string  question;
  std::string  answer;
};
```

You quiz would be a *container* of questions and answers:

```
typedef std::vector<Question_Answer> Quiz_Container;
Quiz_Container politics_quiz;
```

You can overload the stream extraction `operator>>` to have the object read its members from a stream (i.e. file):

```
class Question_Answer
{
  std::string question;
  std::string answer;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, 
                                  Question_Answer& qa);
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input,
                         Question_Answer& qa)
{
  std::getline(input, question);
  std::getline(input, answer);
  return input;
}
```

An input loop could be implemented as:

```
Question_Answer quiz_element;
Quiz            politics_quiz;
while (politic_questions_file >> quiz_element)
{
  politics_quiz.push_back(quiz_element);
}
```

This can be expanded so that a question can have choices and an answer selection:

```
class Question_Answer
{
  std::string  question;
  std::vector<std::string> choices;
  unsigned int answer_choice;
};
```

The concepts presented:

- The quiz element is a question and answer pair (or similar).
- A quiz is a *container* of the quiz elements.
- Overloading the stream extraction `operator>>` allows the quiz
  element to read its own members from a stream.  A stream could be a
  text file.